# server side application in node js deployed in vercel showing error while changing route?

Tags: node.js, routes, vercel

I have deployed my server-side node js application in vercel. I have added the vercel configuration and set the environment variable in the project setting on the site. The application was deployed successfully and working while in the main route. but when I am changing the routes it gives error **Cannot GET /products**. Here **/products** is my route name. [[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yet7e.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdFL0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVaEf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwRAz.png)

I deployed the application again with the command **vercel** in the terminal. but it gives the same error. I am expecting to get the data when I go to the specific routes.